# Is the gamma radiation width equal to total level width in a nuclear reaction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, radiation, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

Consider a nuclear reaction in which an indium nucleus is bombarded by neutrons. The question I am dealing with asks to find the relative probabilities of (n,n) and (n,$\gamma$). The total level width ($\Gamma$) is given.

According to the compound nucleus hypothesis the required ratio comes out to be: $\frac{\Gamma_n}{\Gamma_\gamma}$

where $\Gamma_n$ is partial width for neutron and $\Gamma_\gamma$ is the partial width for $\gamma$ particle.

I found a solution to the question. **In that solution they have used** 
$\Gamma\ =\ \Gamma_\gamma$.

My confusion is: Is there any basis to use the condition $\Gamma\ =\ \Gamma_\gamma$? Or is it just a silly mistake.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange